# open ssrs report in Excel format via 'normal' url with webrequest returns 401

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

i want to download a ssrs report in Excel format in code.

So i first checked the url: it is correct
then i created a webrequest, with a NetworkCredential for the same user which can open the link in the browser.

I moved developing to the ssrs machine itself ( it has vs2008 on it)

so now i'm on the ssrs machine, logged on as user A, starting a webpage, create a webrequest with the same credentials as i'm currently logged on with to the ssrs machine (user A).... and get a 401.

What i don't know is what is giving me the 401. Is it the webserver denying me, or is it ssrs itself (i'm a newbee at ssrs so i don't know much about rights on reports in ssrs itself, but as i said: my logon credentials are the same as the webrequest credentials: user A).

i've googled a lot and tried 5 solutions, but no luck so far.

Comment: Are you able to access the report directly from the local and also from machines?  Also, you say that you're using your logon credentials.  How are you passing the credentials to the web request?

Comment: webrequest.Credential = new networkcredential ("","",""). And on the server, the uri when pasted in IE just opens the report

Comment: What kind of application is it that does the web request? Is it a console or WinForms app or an ASP.NET Web App? Under which user is the application running and does that user have 'Browser' rights on the ssrs?

Answer (score 3):

This won't work if NTLM credentials are required:

```
webrequest.Credential = new networkcredential ("","","");
```

You can try the following but it likely will not work:

```
webrequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Chances are you will need to pass in the actual credentials like:

```
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, Domain);
CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
credCache.Add(new Uri(url), "NTLM", networkCredential);
webrequest.Credentials = credCache;
```

SSRS will need to authentic the WebRequest and default/blank credentials cannot be passed in.

Comment: yeah, sorry, the blank strings were not so smart to type, it was because i didn't want to type the actual strings, so i left them blank. But in my app i entered the right credentials.

Comment: So what are NTLM credentials? Is that some other thing then normal windows user acoount credentials?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to instantiate the webrequest?

Answer (score 2):

This reminded me of something I ran into a couple years ago:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

I'm not sure how likely this problem is, but I really think it's worth implementing "Method 2" from that support article (a simple registry addition) just to see if that resolves the problem. (Yes, the article lists a bunch of old OS versions, but I successfully used this on a bunch of SharePoint 2007 servers to resolve problems.)

Worth a try, I think...

Answer (score 1):

I always set

```
WebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = True
```

Then I run the app as the user accessing the SSRS server.

Answer (score 1):

At first I suggest installing [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) on the machine where the calling application is run. This way you can see exactly the requests and responses that are made between your application and the SSRS. You might find something like an ISA proxy wanting you to additionally authenticate to it.

Assuming your caller is a console or WebForms application, the following code passes the credentials under which your application runs to the SSRS:

```
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = webRequest as HttpWebRequest;

        // request authentication
        httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        // which is the same as
        httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        // optional proxy authentication
        httpWebRequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```